# What does AWS Cloud watch Log Stream represent?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

In AWS Gateway API, if we enable logging using cloud watch settings as shown below, I see quite a few LogStreams in cloud watch. 
[image]

[image]

What are these streams? [Cloudwatch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_LogStream.html) document mentioned below

> Represents a log stream, which is a sequence of log events from a single emitter of logs.

I expect only 1 stream for my API in this case. But I see multiple entries. 
Why do I have so many streams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CloudWatch generates multiple streams due to concurrent access. Only one active connection to API gateway can write to one stream at a time. So, it will generate a new stream for the blocked sessions. Then, when a new session comes up it will choose the newest log stream to write to, which in turn will cause any other concurrent new sessions to generate new streams. Unfortunately, in my experience, it appears that CloudWatch Logs does not have a buffering system in place, so it's a 1-to-1 realtime relationship between sessions and streams.

Comment: Rather than a lack of buffering *per se*, which isn't really a compatible concept since log streams are logical streams written in batches over a stateless interface (not actual, literal streams on a socket or pipe), there's a design limitation in CloudWatch Logs that each stream can only accept 5 messages per second, with 1MB max payload per batch.  [(Source)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/cloudwatch_limits_cwl.html)  To write more than that -- and to group related events contiguously within streams -- multiple streams are needed.